# Spring Boot + Tomcat: RequestMappingHandlerMapping not map requests

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I use Spring Boot + Tomcat.To get war I performed next:

```
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    enabled = true
}

compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.5.10.RELEASE'
```

& inherit Application of SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
            return builder.sources(Application.class);
        }
...
```

After that, war became work in tomcat, but there is a problem - requests not map due RequestMappingHandlerMapping, like they have to:

```
2018-02-15 14:05:01 [main] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/health/activity/all],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.data.domain.Page<ru.example.dto.impl.ActivityDto>> ru.example.controller.impl.ActivityController.getAll(com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)
```

& so on. Attempting to go needed address I see this:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1518692962027,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/health/member"
}
```

Logs:

```
2018-02-15 14:46:53 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/health/member] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
```

Controller class looking like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/health/program")
public class ProgramController extends AbstractCrudController {

@GetMapping(value = "/calculate", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ProgramPackDto> getPrograms(@RequestParam("id") Long id,
                                                         @RequestParam("weight") Double weight) {
        return service.getProgram(id, weight).map(d -> new ResponseEntity<>(d, HttpStatus.OK))
                .orElseGet(() -> new ResponseEntity<>(ResponseEntityUtils.createHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK));
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: show your package strucutre. where is your controller (in which package) and where is your main class? do you have `@ComponentScan(...)`

Comment: There is nothing matching `"/health/member"` in your controller .

Comment: pvpkiran - all controllers scanned by ComponentScan, I checked

Comment: Berger - I have several controllers, including health/member & health/program. noone maps

Comment: when you start your application, do you see the controller mappings listed?

Comment: pvpkiran - no, only /error & /**

Comment: Hey, did you got fix for this ? I am facing similar issue

Comment: Did you find a solution?